# HashMap actual element's index

Tags: java, indexing, hashmap, key

I have a HashMap with Integer, String datatypes as an incoming parameter.

```
 (LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> linc);
```

The data inside are:

1,Test |
 2,Test |
 4,Test

I need to read the HashMap's key, value, and the index number.

Is it possible? (1 , 1 , test | 2, 2, test | 3, 4, test)

So far I can reach the second and the third:

```
for (int j = 0; j < linc.size(); j++) {

j = index number | lic.get(j) = value | key = ?

}
```

Comment: Do you want just one triple (key, value, index) (E.g. for some key), or do you want the triple for all entries?

Comment: I would like it for all entries, but I am intrested in both solutions just to know how is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this triple for all entries, you will need to use the entry set's iterator, and maintain a parallel count of the element index:

```
int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  Key key = entry.getKey();
  Value value = entry.getValue();

  // Whatever code using (key, value, index)...

  ++index;
}
```

---

I can't think of a good way to do it for just a single key with LinkedHashMap: I think you'd have to pretty much do the same thing, and just break out of the loop once you've found the key of interest.

If you are able to use Guava's ImmutableMap, you would be able to locate the index of a key thus:

```
int index = immutableMap.keySet().asList().indexOf(key)
```

and hence get the corresponding value:

```
immutableMap.values().asList().get(index);
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! Perfect and understandable